# why there is gap between absolutely positioned child and parent which has 1px border

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Why small gap appears between child and parent when child absolutely positioned and parent have 1px border? Appears in chrome and opera but not in firefox.

Sample Screenshot

[image: Sample Screenshot]

example Codepen: https://codepen.io/stasqlx/pen/oNwKjxz

```css
.parent {
  height: 300px;
  width: 170px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
}
.child {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">hello</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Which versions of the browsers do you use?

Comment: You don't need `width` if you also set `right: 0;`

Comment: Change `border-width` from 1px to 0.5px.

Comment: @yourbraineatsyou appears in `Chrome 94.0.4606.71`

Comment: @decpk  `right: 0` doesn't help with the problem

Comment: Hi ! I can't reproduce this issue with the snippet, thought I'm using Chrome 94.0.4606.71. Are you sure that no other CSS you may use in the real case interfere with the rules you provided ?

Comment: @Philippe I have that issue with example on codepen. I don't have other css rules

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I'm no more able to reproduce the issue on codepen. For me, everything works as expected :(

Comment: Cannot reproduce on codepen, nor SO snippet.